# Keeping TeX Live 2013 updated on Windows

Tags: installing, texlive, windows

I downloaded TeX Live 2013 using the torrent for the *.iso image, because I figured it would be faster than the net-install. However, I am now having issues updating TeX Live 2013.

Here's what happens:

1. I run TeX Live Manager (GUI)
2. I press the "Update all installed" button
3. I then get the following message: [image]
4. I press "Ok", and then some stuff happens (usually before I can press "Update all installed" again, and I get the following message:[image]
5. I press "Ok" again, and Tex Live Manager closes
6. Go back to 1, repeat forever

Why am I stuck in this loop?

Comment: What if you open a command prompt (search in the start menu, and you'll find it) and enter `tlmgr update --self --all`?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. http://i.imgur.com/6hxB9AL.png

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Why not just try the net installer?

Comment: @Werner Guess I'll have to!

Comment: @twirlobite: Well, it's worth a shot if you keep experiencing problems using the current setup.

Comment: Have you tried a different mirror? Sometimes some of the mirrors behave badly

Comment: Perhaps a user right issue. Where did you install? Did you install as admin? Do you start the package manager now with admin rights (elevated)?

Comment: @Speravir I did install as the admin, and I am not sure if I ran the package manager with admit rights (but usually, everything I do has full admin rights). I already uninstalled it and got the net-install running though, so maybe that will fix things.

Comment: @twirlobite: Yepp, maybe. Last exit would be the portable version.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a localized problem, that cannot be retraced by other people.